# Prove that $-(-x) = x$ for all real numbers x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Is the following a complete proof? It is from the book, $Prealgebra$ by R. Rusczyk, D. Patrick, and R. Boppana

Consider the sum

$$x + (-x) + (-(-x)).$$

That is, we are adding x, its negation -x, and the negation of -x. By associative property of addition, we can add these three in any order. If we start by adding the first two, we have $x + (-x) = 0$, so

$$x + (-x) + (-(-x)) = 0 + (-(-x)) = -(-x).$$

However, suppose we start by adding $(-x) + (-(-x))$ first. Since $(-(-x))$ is the negation of $-x$, we have $(-x) + (-(-x)) = 0.$ So, we find

$$x + (-x) + (-(-x)) = x + 0 = x.$$

We just showed that $x + (-x) + (-(-x))$ equals both $-(-x)$ and $x$, so we must have

$$-(-x) = x.$$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: This is correct. The only thing I'd suggest is, when using associativity, add the parentheses directly into your work. For example, when adding $-x$ and $-(-x)$, write $x + \left[(-x) + (-(-x))\right] = x + 0 = x$. You might also want to note that this final step uses the additive identity axiom. But, this proof is certainly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems to be correct indeed by axioms we have

$$-x-(-x) = 0 $$

then

$$x=x\iff x+[-x-(-x)] = x+0 \iff -(-x) = x $$

Answer (score 0):

If we explicitly acknowledge that that existence of additive inverses means that there exists an element $-(-x)$ such that $-x+-(-x)=0$, we have,by the associativity of addition and the reflexivity of equality:

$$(x+-x)+-(-x)=x+(-x+-(-x))$$

By the definition of additive inverse 
$x+-x=0$ and $-x+-(-x)=0$ so:

$$0+-(-x)=x+0$$

By the definition of additive identity 
$-(-x)+0=-(-x)$ and $x+0=x$ therefore:

$$-(-x)=x$$